# Relation tables with PHP and MySQL for big databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a set of questions for a new site I'm making. I will be glad for all help I can get.

Let's say I have the tables

1. members (memberId, memberName)
2. images (imageId, imageName)

A member should be able to "like" images, so I'm thinking of making a relation-table like

1. likes (memberId, imageId)

This way, when watching images, I could just check if the user has this imageId as a like.

How could I set up this to make it work for big databases (lets say 200K users and 1M images)

First of all I guess memberId in (1.) and imageId in (2.) should be set as primary keys.

**Question 1:** How do I build the table (3. likes)

When displaying the images I would like to show how many "likes" each image has, and I believe for large databases, a count on rows would be too heave, so I guess a field has to be added to the database images (2.) called "likes" which just gets a +1 each time someone likes it.

**Question 2:** Is this the correct way of doing it?
When watching the images as a logged in user, I would like to know if I already has "liked" an image.

**Question 3:** Should i before the list make an array of the ones a user has "liked" and then match when listing, or make a database call each time we print an image?

**Question 4:** Should I even bother having a relation-table in this setup, or should I just have a field in the database members (1.) with something like comma seperated id:s for the images liked (for extra performance?

Comment: could you predict the size of your data specificly?

Comment: Please [take the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - then you'll learn that this is "_not a discussion forum_" and you should "_Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 200k users and 1M images should be absolutely no problem. Your're right about tables members and images with the primary keys. Your likes table should contain the memberId and imageId and I personally would add a timestamp (when did the person liked the image). This likes-table should have a combined primary key of memberId,imageId (prevents someone from liking an image several times).

The primary keys will automatically generate indexes, which should make querying the tables very fast. You might add two more indexes to the likes table: one for memberId and one for imageId.

Your questions:

1. A count with an index should be really fast. No problem. Don't make extra fields with counts in the images-table.
2. See above. Should be no problem
3. Don't understand the question. What list? If you are afraid of using too many database calls, take a look at memcached or something similar, to cache data.
4. Do use a relation-table.

Comment: All I needed to clear out everything, big thanks!